# svg - overflow visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to create an svg containing circles. The size of each circle can change overtime and sometimes it gets bigger than my svg so I'd like to make the overflow visible but somehow it is not working:

HTML:

```
<svg class="container1" width="100px">
    <a class="g-node" xlink:href="#test" transform="translate(445,194)" stroke="black">
        <circle r="16.246572566634875" fill="red"></circle>
    </a>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.container1{
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LuwWa/

Is there any way to make the overflow visible?

thanks

Comment: Where do you want to paint a circle when there is no paper (container)?

Comment: use a div container for overflow attribute

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your CSS selector is `.container` but your svg elements have classes `container1` and `container2`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LuwWa/2/)